# Create Multiple records for a model with a single form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have one model 'Schedule' in my application and want a user to add multiple schedule with a single form but how can I save multiple records with a single form without using **nested_form_for** and  **fields_for**.

Please help.
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

You really would need to provide some code to show us what you're doing.  However...

Remember that what actually happens when the user submits the form is handled entirely by the schedule controller, specifically the `create` action.  For example, if you were creating a repeating event that occurred every week or month, you could certainly include logic in your controller to cause multiple events to be scheduled from that single submission.

Whether you think that logic should be in the controller or possibly in the model is a design decision that you'd have to make.  Personally, I would recommend pushing it into the model since it really is a function of the model..  What I'm getting at is that you may instantiate or handle a `Schedule` object somewhere else, possibly in some other controller.  Rather than duplicating code, moving all scheduling activities into the model allows you to keep it DRY.